# Autocomplete text in ember Js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, autocomplete, handlebars.js

I am new in pretty ember js.please look below url.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/loqivasova/1/edit?html,css,js,output..

This Url Showing Two drop down List using ember js.
I would be like to change  first drop down autocomplete text.
Any one share useful links about autocomplete text with ember js

Comment: Well what you want to do ? Replace the first <select> by a text input with autocompletion or replace the data in the first <select> because from your title and what you write im not sure we can understand what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to incorporate jQuery-ui autocomplete functionality from [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) into an Ember component.

```
App.XAutocompleteComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
  autocomplete: function(){
    var availableTags = [
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
    ];

    this.$().autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

You can then use the component in your template as follows:

```
{{ x-autocomplete value=result}}
```

Full example on jsbin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/genobasuwi/1/edit?html,js,output)